# OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found in pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, fbs

I am a beginner in python and trying to convert a .py script into .exe using a derivative of pyinstaller known as fbs, so this question is probably dumb, I apologize in advance.

I used it following the instructions using python 3.6.7 and importing all the modules in the virtual environment as directed. the program run but fbs freeze didn't work. turning the 'Failed to execute script main' error. I run the fbs freeze --debug method and now I am finding this error:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 172, in init
File "ctypes_init_.py", line 348, in init
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found**
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
'''''''''
''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''

File "lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 174, in init
main.PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll 'C:\Users\ALEXIS\Desktop\DEVELOP\target\Test5\sklearn.**libs\vcomp140.dll'. Most probably this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen.
[6916] Failed to execute script main**

I have tried some solutions that suggested adding --path to the folder that contains Qt5Widgets.dll,"Qt5Core.dll"] and "Qt5Gui.dll" without success. I also tried to add these dll files in the json file as Hidden imports but it didn't work as well.

I hope you can point me in the right direction.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

My answer on this thread might be of help to include various resources upon `fbs freeze`.

[The 'google-api-python-client' distribution was not found and is required by the application with pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61510900/the-google-api-python-client-distribution-was-not-found-and-is-required-by-the/61531259#61531259)

Comment: Thanks @joeyipanimation. I solved the problem by first installing the numpy-1.18.2+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl version from [link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and then when I run fbs freeze--debug I was shown that the mkl_avx2.dll were the problems by copying all the mkl_xxx.dll from the environment folder (venv\Lib\site-packages\numpy)  to the target folder where the frozen app is. Voila everthing worked fine, the app run with no error.

Comment: Glad to help! Can you mark question as solved (and maybe upvote the answer please?) Cheers!